# Time in hh:mmXM format

Tags: c#, date

I want Time in this format: `hh:mmXM`

I can get the date with:

```
Date now = new Date();
```

Is there a way to get the time in that format from now?

Comment: See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?...

Comment: What do you expect for "XM"?

Comment: @StephanMoolman: I've *never* seen anything use that notation before. .NET uses `tt`.

Comment: Also, what is the `Date` type here? That looks more like Java than .NET...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am converting a clarion application and that was the format in the documentation.

Comment: Please be more specific in future - the fact that you didn't give any examples or even *mention* Clarion is unhelpful. And again, it's not clear what the `Date` type is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mmtt");
```

Checkout this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string currentTime = now.ToString("HH:mmtt");
```